# Select first instance of a vector in a column

Tags: string, r, vector, dataframe

I have an output from a matching function. In some cases the function cannot select one out of two or more names from the matching and hence stores them both/all in a vector within the column.

What i want to accomplish is to select the first, second, third.. instance of the vector in the column to proceed.

Here is a replication data frame:

```
string <- c("c(\"Kaskazini 'A'\", \"Kaskazini 'B'\")","c(\"Kabale\", \"Kabare\")","c(\"Kisoko\", \"Kisoro Tc\")",
            "c(\"Luwero East\", \"Luwero West\")", "c(\"Marindi\", \"Malindi\")",c("c(\"Mukongoro\", \"Mukono Tc\", \"Muko\")")
)

testdf <- data.frame(string
           )
```

Comment: Could you pleasse specify expected output?

Comment: `lapply(lapply(as.character(testdf$string), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))), "[", c(1, 2))` will give you e.g. the 1st & 2nd *instance* with your example data.

Comment: The expected output is a new vector/column with only the first names of the vector within the column.

Comment: Then second, third ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

```
string <- c("c(\"Kaskazini 'A'\", \"Kaskazini 'B'\")","c(\"Kabale\", \"Kabare\")","c(\"Kisoko\", \"Kisoro Tc\")",
            "c(\"Luwero East\", \"Luwero West\")", "c(\"Marindi\", \"Malindi\")",c("c(\"Mukongoro\", \"Mukono Tc\", \"Muko\")")
)

testdf <- data.frame(string)
#convert all quotes into pipe symbol for use as a delimiter
testdf$string <- gsub('"',"|",testdf$string)
#split the string using pipe
testdf$strsplit <- strsplit(testdf$string, "|",fixed=TRUE)
#extract first name using sapply
testdf$first <- sapply(testdf$strsplit, function(x) x[[2]])
#extract second name using sapply
testdf$second <- sapply(testdf$strsplit, function(x) x[[4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way with regular expressions:

```
# extract instances (in a list)
strings <- regmatches(testdf$string, 
                      gregexpr("(?<=\")[^\"]+?(?=\"[,)])", 
                               testdf$string, perl = TRUE))

[[1]]
[1] "Kaskazini 'A'" "Kaskazini 'B'"
[[2]]
[1] "Kabale" "Kabare"
[[3]]
[1] "Kisoko"    "Kisoro Tc"
[[4]]
[1] "Luwero East" "Luwero West"
[[5]]
[1] "Marindi" "Malindi"
[[6]]
[1] "Mukongoro" "Mukono Tc" "Muko"     


# add columns to `testdf`
testdf$first <- sapply(strings, "[", 1)
testdf$second <- sapply(strings, "[", 2)
testdf$third <- sapply(strings, "[", 3)

                               string         first        second third
1 c("Kaskazini 'A'", "Kaskazini 'B'") Kaskazini 'A' Kaskazini 'B'  <NA>
2               c("Kabale", "Kabare")        Kabale        Kabare  <NA>
3            c("Kisoko", "Kisoro Tc")        Kisoko     Kisoro Tc  <NA>
4     c("Luwero East", "Luwero West")   Luwero East   Luwero West  <NA>
5             c("Marindi", "Malindi")       Marindi       Malindi  <NA>
6 c("Mukongoro", "Mukono Tc", "Muko")     Mukongoro     Mukono Tc  Muko
```

If you don't want to create all columns manually or don't know the maximum number of instances, you can use the following approach:

```
res <- sapply(seq(max(sapply(strings, length))), function(x) 
  sapply(strings, "[", x))

cbind(testdf, res)

                               string             1             2    3
1 c("Kaskazini 'A'", "Kaskazini 'B'") Kaskazini 'A' Kaskazini 'B' <NA>
2               c("Kabale", "Kabare")        Kabale        Kabare <NA>
3            c("Kisoko", "Kisoro Tc")        Kisoko     Kisoro Tc <NA>
4     c("Luwero East", "Luwero West")   Luwero East   Luwero West <NA>
5             c("Marindi", "Malindi")       Marindi       Malindi <NA>
6 c("Mukongoro", "Mukono Tc", "Muko")     Mukongoro     Mukono Tc Muko
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for providing the example!